# Items from old blog added to Google Reader appear as read, want them unread

Tags: google-reader

I recently added an older blog to my Google Reader (it doesn't have any posts within the last year).  Because of this all posts show as "read".  So, if I browse by viewing "all items", all the posts show.  But because they are all "read", I can't hide posts from the view by marking them as "read".

Ideally I would like to be able to mark these old items as "unread" and have a shortcut to mark all of the items in this old feed as "unread".

I see that I can tag individual posts in the feed as "unread".  And then I can browse the "unread" tag, and remove individual posts from the tag as I like.  The big flaw with this, is that I have to manually mark each post as "unread".

How can I hide posts when everything in a feed is marked as "read"?

Answer (score 1):

Google Reader doesn't allow marking items older than 30 days as unread. Thus, you have only 2 options:

1. Continue with your manual workaround
2. Use a 3rd-party client, such as [FeedDemon](http://www.feeddemon.com/) that syncs with Google Reader and may allow for marking old articles as unread.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I hide posts when everything in a feed is marked as "read"?

As shown in the screenshot below, make sure you have "New Items" selected from the drop-down menu, and NOT "All Items". That way, posts that are marked as "read" are hidden from the feed.

[image: Screenshot]